# Detectron2 Mask-Rcnn keep same color segmentation for same object class

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, detectron

I am using [detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) implementation of Mask-Rcnn on video, the problem is that on each frame, the segmentation color of a same object change.

Is there any parameter that can allow me to keep a single color for an object class.
I already tried detectron2.utils.visualizer.ColorMode(1) and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColorMode(1)` only has an effect if the metadata passed to the `Visualizer` has `thing_colors` defined. From the [documentation for ColorMode](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html#detectron2.utils.visualizer.ColorMode),

> SEGMENTATION= 1
>
> > Let instances of the same category have similar colors
> > (from metadata.thing_colors), and overlay them with high opacity. This
> > provides more attention on the quality of segmentation.

So, **you need to add a list of pre-defined colors (one for each class) to your metadata**. From [here](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/datasets.html#metadata-for-datasets),

> `thing_colors` (list[tuple(r, g, b)]): Pre-defined color (in [0, 255]) for each thing category. Used for visualization. If not given, random colors will be used.

Now, the actual colors used may not be the exact same ones as specified in `thing_colors`. In [`Visualizer.draw_instance_predictions()`](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/detectron2/utils/visualizer.html#Visualizer.draw_instance_predictions), each specified color is jittered by adding a random value to it, so the overlaid color is a slightly different one. This use of a random value means that you will still see class colors change between frames. Depending on the colors you specify, this change may or may not be visually obvious.

A simple solution to this might be to subclass `Visualizer` and override the `_jitter()` method so that it returns the color as is.

```py
class MyVisualizer(Visualizer):
    def _jitter(self, color):
        return color
```

However, `_jitter()` is intended to be an internal method, so this is a hacky solution, and might break sometime down the line.

A better solution might be to override `draw_instance_predictions()` and customize the drawing to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer ,  GenericMask , ColorMode

MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]).thing_classes = clss
MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]).thing_colors = [(255,255,0),(0,0,255),(0,255,0),(255,0,255),(156,225,242)]
class MyVisualizer(Visualizer):
    def _jitter(self, color ):
        return color
v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]), scale=1.2,instance_mode=ColorMode.SEGMENTATION)
v = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
img = cv2.resize(v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1], (1220, 780))
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I customize the visualization color and it worked.

```python
# Retrieve the validation dataset
metadata_valid = MetadataCatalog.get('data-valid')

# Add 'thing_colors' to metadata without setting its values
# Note: the 'thing_colors' field can be only set once and cannot be changed later
metadata_valid.set(thing_colors=None)

prediction_color = [0, 255, 0] # green for predctions

dataset_valid = DatasetCatalog.get(VALID_DATA_SET_NAME)
metadata = MetadataCatalog.get(VALID_DATA_SET_NAME)

# Run model on the validation dataset
for d in dataset_valid:
    img = cv2.imread(d["file_name"])
    outputs = predictor(img)

    # Visualize predictions
    visualizer_pred = Visualizer(
        img[:, :, ::-1],
        metadata=metadata,
        scale=0.8,
        instance_mode=ColorMode.SEGMENTATION  
    )
    # Set a single color for all predictions
    for cls in metadata.thing_classes:
        visualizer_pred.metadata.thing_colors[metadata.thing_classes.index(cls)] = prediction_color
    out_pred = visualizer_pred.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
```

Hope it helps!